# Create two-way connection between pages in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I wonder if there is possibility to create two-way connection between pages. I want to write tests which references to method in both a specific pages and the common class at any time.
Sample diagram:

[image: Create two-way connection between pages in Selenium Java]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can Inherit the common page Class in Internal employee class, External employee class such that you can Access methods of common class aka (base Class) in children classes